# Using scipy colors and imsave on a OS X 10.7 (Lion)

Tags: python, numpy, osx-lion, scipy

I'm trying to run imsave and imshow and basic scipy functionality dealing with colors in arrays on OS X 10.7 to no avail. Here's my code, and then following that I'll post my error. Is there some way to fix or go around this on a permanent basis so I can use this functionality on my mac? I've run this identical code on a Linux machine running Ubuntu and have had success.

```
from numpy import *
from scipy import *

a = zeros((3,500,400))

a[1,0:100,0:200] = 255


imsave('foo.png',a)
```

If this works correctly I should simply get a black box 500x400 pixels, and a green box inside of that 100x200 pixels in the top left corner. 
but instead I get this error

"Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "colorstuff.py", line 10, in 
    imsave('foo.png',a)
NameError: name 'imsave' is not defined"

and a similar error for imshow.

Any ideas on how to go about avoiding this error?

(on a sidenote, i have tried importing from scipy.misc and get the exact same errors)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit:

I misread your question.  I thought `imsave` wasn't saving your image properly, but that you were able to import it.

`scipy.misc.imsave` is just a thin wrapper around [PIL (the python imaging library)](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/). You need to install PIL for it to work.

<strike>What happens if you just use PIL directly?</strike>

`scipy.misc.imsave` dates from many years ago when `Image` didn't support numpy arrays. It's not officially depreciated, but it jumps through a lot of hoops that aren't necessary with recent versions of PIL.

What happens if you do this:

```
import numpy as np
import Image

# It's easier to work with a MxNx3 array instead of a 3xMxN array in PIL
a = np.zeros((500, 400, 3))
a[:100, :200, 1] = 255

im = Image.fromarray(a.astype(np.uint8))
im.save('test.png')
```

Also, avoid doing `from whatever import *`.  It's only there for interactive use. It's a very bad idea otherwise.  (In the case of `numpy`, you're over-riding many python's builtin functions with the numpy versions with don't do the same thing.) Also, don't use the base `scipy` namespace. It's just `numpy` with one or two extra functions.  *All* of scipy is in its submodules. Import what you need directly (e.g. `from scipy.misc import imsave`)

Comment: I just tried running what you had in there, and instantly had an error telling me that there was no module named Image. Is that built into python? or where is that coming from?

Comment: It's the [python imaging library](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/).  That's odd... You must have it, or otherwise `scipy.misc.imsave` wouldn't be available... (Or it would throw an error, at any rate. `imsave` is just a thin wrapper around `Image`.)

Comment: You need to do from `PIL import Image` instead. Give it a try and see if that works...

Comment: Joe, I got a similar error telling me there was no module named PIL

Comment: So, `from scipy.misc import imsave` works but `import Image` doesn't? I'm very confused... What happens when you do `import scipy.misc.pilutil`?  (`imsave` is actually in `pilutil`) Can you access `scipy.misc.pilutil.Image`?

Comment: When I import scipy.misc.pilutil I get an error saying "No module named Image"
and actually get the same for all of the things you just posted. so the from scipy,misc import imsave doesn't work. I said it works on linux, but not on my mac if that's confusing you at all

Comment: Oh! I was confused! You just need to install `PIL`. I thought `imsave` was working, but wasn't saving the image properly.

Answer (score 1):

From the SciPy manual:

> Note that the Python Imaging Library (PIL) is not a dependency of SciPy and therefore the pilutil module is not available on systems that don’t have PIL installed.

You need to install PIL for OSX. I'm not sure if it is available.